# LIbreOffice 3.4.4 won't update

Tags: libreoffice

I have ubuntu 11.10 installed on my machine and LibreOffice 3.4.4 came with it. Since I know there is a newer version out there, I ran the following commands:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
```

However it won't install a newer version and I'm stuck with 3.4.4 (a version I'm not completely a fan of). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you may need to update your version of Ubuntu to 12.04 to take advantage of the newer versions of LibreOffice.

Remember some newer software does not always work on older operating systems.

If you do decide to update your version of Ubuntu all you need to do is go to update manager > settings > then make sure you have notify me of new Ubuntu version (go with the LTS versions) and that will give you the option to download a newer version of Ubuntu and plus an updated version of LibreOffice

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa/+packages) only provides packages for: 
Lucid - 10.04 LTS 
Precise - 12.04 LTS 
Quantal - 12.10

It doesn't have any packages for Oneiric - 11.10, which is about to go End of Life on May 9. I'd also suggest upgrading asap.